# Need a suggestion on how to merge datasets with similar but not identical joint id

Tags: sas

So what I have is a data set that has each city and state in one column. The other data set also has city and state in one column BUT some of the cities are combined. For example:

Data set one will have:

```
CITY STATE          POPULATION
Cape Coral Fl       1000000    
Fort Myers FL       2000000    
Gainesville FL      100000
```

Data set two will have:

```
CITY STATE                    EMPLOYMENT    
Cape Coral - Fort Myers FL    900    
Gainesville FL                1000
```

I thought about doing a "fuzzy" match, but then for the hyphenated cities I won't get the full population. I could try to break up the hyphenated cities and then dividing the employment in half, but I don't know how to do that.

I am hoping there is an easier solution out there that I haven't thought of. I went ahead and did a traditional merge by CITY STATE, but it only matched half of my data set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think if you had a Master list of regions (i.e.: cape corral, Gainesville, etc) then there is a clear path... We need a fixed set of regions to correlate the other 2, "population data" and "employment data". Do you follow? I'll try to form a response given some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The second data set can be broken into more rows if you make some assumptions, such as each component city is separated by dash (-) and state is always last piece.

```
data two;
  length city_state $100;
  input CITY_STATE & EMPLOYMENT;
datalines;
Cape Coral - Fort Myers FL    900    
Gainesville FL                1000
run;

data two_b;
  length city_state_item $100;
  set two;
  state = scan (city_state, -1, ' ');
  p = find (city_state, trim(state), -101);
  city_state_base = substr(city_state,1,p-1);
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 while (scan(city_state_base,_n_,'-') ne '');
    city_state_item = catx (' ', scan(city_state_base,_n_,'-'), state);
    OUTPUT;
    employment = 0;
  end;
  drop p city_state_base state;
run;
```

After splitting you will have to match `ONE.city_state` to `TWO_B.city_state_item` and deal with how employment will be split or not split depending on how the matched data get re-aggregated or used to compute some employment to population ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions this solution could work:

```
data a;
  length city_state $100;
  input CITY_STATE & POPULATION;
  datalines;
  Cape Coral Fl       1000000    
  Fort Myers FL       2000000    
  Gainesville FL      100000
run;

data  b;
  length city_state $100;
  input CITY_STATE & EMPLOYMENT;
  datalines;
  Cape Coral - Fort Myers FL    900    
  Gainesville FL                1000
Run;

Proc sql;
select a.city_state, b.city_state, a.population, case when b.city_state contains '-' then b.EMPLOYMENT /2 else b.EMPLOYMENT End as EMPLOYMENT from a
 inner join b 
on b.city_state contains substr(a.city_state,1,length(a.city_state)-length(scan(a.city_state,-1,' ')));
quit;
```

result:

```
city_state     | city_state                 |POPULATION |EMPLOYMENT 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cape Coral Fl  | Cape Coral - Fort Myers FL | 1000000   |  450 
Fort Myers FL  | Cape Coral - Fort Myers FL | 2000000   |  450 
Gainesville FL | Gainesville FL             | 100000    | 1000
```

Assuming every city_state with a - includes two city states, you can half it

> case when b.city_state contains '-' then b.EMPLOYMENT /2 else b.EMPLOYMENT End as EMPLOYMENT

Assuming every city_state ends with the short state, you can remove the state and do a contains statement:

> b.city_state contains substr(a.city_state,1,length(a.city_state)-length(scan(a.city_state,-1,' ')));